# How do I evaluate this limit with an integral function?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

Could anybody give me some pointers on how do I evaluate this limit:

$$\lim_{t \to +\infty} \frac{\int_0^t x^9e^{-x^2}\,dx}{\int_0^t x^7e^{-x^2}\,dx}$$

I'm not asking for the complete solution, just a hint to point me in the right direction. I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: The integrals converge, so though it is technically a limit it might be clearer to instead think of this as evaluating the ratio $$\frac{\int_0^\infty x^9e^{-x^2}\,dx}{\int_0^\infty x^7e^{-x^2}\,dx}.$$

Comment: Start with $$x^2=u$$ and try to derive reduction formula

Comment: After substituting $t=x^2$, see [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: Thanks for the substitution idea. I'd thought of it before, but I was not sure it would lead to a manageable solution. Using reduction formula solved the problem though. ellya's solution is also similar.

Comment: Thanks to the $\Gamma$ function, you will obtain the values of both integrals, $12$ and $3$ respectively. So the ratio is $12/3 = 4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need to evaluate the integrals. 
Integrating by parts we obtain
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} x^9 e^{-x^2}dx&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} x^8 (-2x)e^{-x^2}dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\left[x^8 e^{-x^2} \right]_0^{\infty}+\frac{8}{2}\int_0^{\infty} x^7 e^{-x^2}dx\\
&=4\int_0^{\infty} x^7 e^{-x^2}dx.
\end{align}
So
$$
\frac{\int_0^{\infty} x^9 e^{-x^2}dx}{\int_0^{\infty} x^7 e^{-x^2}dx}=4.
$$
I think the hint "integration by parts" would not be enough, but I left some details for you to make complete the calculations.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
With $\ds{\mu > 0}$:
\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{{\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{9}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x} \over  \ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{7}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x}}}
=\left.-\,\partiald{}{\mu}\ln\pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{7}\expo{-\mu x^{2}}\,\dd x}
\right\vert_{\mu\ =\ 1}
\\[3mm]&=\left.-\,\partiald{}{\mu}\ln\pars{\mu^{-4}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{7}
\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x}\right\vert_{\mu\ =\ 1}
=\left.-\,\partiald{\ln\pars{\mu^{-4}}}{\mu}\right\vert_{\mu\ =\ 1}
=\left.{4 \over \mu}\right\vert_{\mu\ =\ 1}
=\color{#00f}{\Large 4}
\end{align}

Comment: I'm not familiar with this technique. Where can I learn more about it?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\int_0^tx^9e^{-x^2}dx}{\int_0^tx^7e^{-x^2}}=\frac{-\frac{1}{2}(e^{-t^2}(t^8+4t^6+12t^4+24t^2+24)+24)}{-\frac{1}{2}(e^{-t^2}(t^6+3t^4+6t^2+6)+6)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}e^{-t^2}(t^8+4t^6+12t^4+24t^2+24+24e^{t^2})}{\frac{1}{2}(e^{-t^2}(t^6+3t^4+6t^2+6+6e^{t^2}))}=\frac{t^8+4t^6+12t^4+24t^2+24+24e^{t^2}}{t^6+3t^4+6t^2+6+6e^{t^2}}=\frac{e^{-t^2}(t^8+4t^6+12t^4+24t^2+24)+24}{e^{-t^2}(t^6+3t^4+6t^2+6)+6}\to 4\,\,\,,\,as\,t\to\infty$

Comment: That doesn't seem right. The integrals definitely converge, that I know for sure (plotted it on a grapher).

Comment: sorry, i missed out a constant, when putting in the values for $x=t,x=0$.